# Sum values with one-to-many relationship

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have two entities ***Transaction*** and ***Account***. one Account holds many transactions. I use this piece of code to calculate the sum of all transactions (of all accounts):

```
let sum = transactions.map { $0.value }.reduce(0, +)
```

But I don't know how to sum transactions that belongs to each account. I have a ForEach that shows each account and I want to put also the sum of their transactions. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Edit:
Heres the core data model:

```
Account+CoreDataProperties.swift
    
@NSManaged public var bank: String?
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var iban: String?
@NSManaged public var city: String?
@NSManaged public var postal: String?
@NSManaged public var street: String?
@NSManaged public var country: String?
@NSManaged public var transaction: NSSet?
    
public var wrappedName: String 
   name ?? "Unknown Account" 
}

//...

Transaction+CoreDataProperties.swift

@NSManaged public var category: String?
    @NSManaged public var comment: String?
    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var name: String?
    @NSManaged public var value: Double
    @NSManaged public var account: Account?

public var wrappedName: String {
        name ?? "Unknown Transaction"
    }

    public var wrappedComment: String {
        comment ?? "Unknown Comment"
    }

//...
```

Comment: It would help if you showed the models of `Transaction` and `Account` because the code is much too esoteric otherwise.

Comment: Done, I hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that each account records all of its transactions; iterate through the accounts and sum their transactions.

```
for account in accounts {
    let sumForThisAccount = account.transactions.map { $0.value }.reduce(0, +)
}
```